# What does the sound and flashing button indicate during this landing?

Tags: landing, feature-identification, cockpit-alerts, bombardier-crj

What does the sound in [this](https://youtu.be/YbZjLNL6IAs?t=602) YouTube video indicate? It is accompanied by a flashing button.

Does that sound indicate the touchdown of both the main and nose landing gear? The pilot also pressed the same button at the end of the video.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the "Master Caution" indication. The sound also belongs to this.

It tells you that something is not working by the books and that you should check it out immediately.

There was probably another indication lit as well giving more details about what is going wrong. But since the screens are covered (and I'm not experienced enough to tell from what's going on in the video) I don't know what exact issue occurred.

However, you see the First Officer taking care of it. Either he fixed it or decided that it was a no-issue so he presses the "Master Caution" button to turn the warning off.

Comment: Do you happen to know the resources that consists of different sounds aircraft produces like [this](http://www.fluglärm-portal.de/laerm-vermeiden/moderne-flugzeuge/oberflaeche-fluegel-fahrwerk/)?

Comment: @Auberron The sound are described in the [CRJ manual - CHAPTER 2 - AURAL/VISUAL INDICATING AND RECORDING](https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/CRJ-00_and_00-Aural_Visual_Indicating_and_Recording.pdf).

Comment: When Cautions come up like that on short final you just kill the MC and carry on the landing.